# JavaScript array split at index

Tags: javascript

I have an array like:

```
var arr = ['Number 1', 'name', 'Number 2', 'name']
```

How can I get a string from this array that looks like this:

```
var str = 'Number 1: name, Number 2: name'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this, you'd probably want `Array#reduce`, see the comments:

```js
// The array
var arr = ['Number 1', 'name', 'Number 2', 'name']

// Start with no delimiter
var delim = "";

// Array#reduce calls the callback once for each entry, passing in
// the accumulator as the first argument and the entry as the second
var str = arr.reduce(function(acc, entry) {
    // Add this entry onto the accumulator
    acc += delim + entry;

    // Toggle between ", " and ": " as the delim (the first time we have
    // "", which means we'll switch to ": ")
    delim = delim === ", " ? ": " : ", ";

    // Return the new value of the delim
    return acc;
}, "");
// ^^---- initial value of the accumulator is blank

document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + str + "</pre>";
```

Alternately, you can do it with the other variant of `reduce` where you don't give an initial value for the accumulator:

```js
// The array
var arr = ['Number 1', 'name', 'Number 2', 'name']

// Start with the first delimiter we want to use
var delim = ": ";

// Array#reduce calls the callback slightly differently the
// first time: It passes entry 0 as the first argument and entry 1
// as the second. From then on it keeps passing the accumulator.
var str = arr.reduce(function(acc, entry) {
    // Add this entry onto the accumulator
    acc += delim + entry;

    // Toggle between ", " and ": " as the delim (the first time we have
    // "", which means we'll switch to ": ")
    delim = delim === ": " ? ", " : ": ";

    // Return the new value of the delim
    return acc;
});

document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + str + "</pre>";
```

Or actually, you could use `map` and `join`:

```js
// The array
var arr = ['Number 1', 'name', 'Number 2', 'name']

// Append the desired delimiter to each entry except the last,
// then join the resulting array
var str = arr.map(function(entry, index) {
    if (index < arr.length - 1) {
        entry += index % 2 == 1 ? ", " : ": ";
    }
    return entry;
}).join("");

document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + str + "</pre>";
```

Comment: @NinaScholz: Yes! :-)

Comment: @quarrazzella: np. I added an alternative at the end :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by,

```
var arr = ['Number 1', 'name', 'Number 2', 'name'],res ="";
for(var i=0,len=arr.length;i<len;i+=2){
  res += arr[i] + ":" + arr[i+1] + ((i+2 != len) ? "," : "");
}
```

set your for loop's step as 2. During iteration get the array's values related to `current index` and `current index + 1`. Concatenate it by giving a delimiter as `:`. And your job is done.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dm9wkmgw/)

Comment: this answer is a nice option too! I didn't mark it cause TJ offered a variety of options

Comment: @quarrazzella Yeah. You are free to accept whatever you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.join()` with `.replace()`:

```js
var arr = ['Number 1', 'name', 'Number 2', 'name'];

var s = arr.join(',').replace(/(\d)+/g, '$1:').replace(/(:,)/g, ':');

document.write('<pre>'+s+'</pre>')
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you correct output as needed ->

```
    var str = "";
    var arr = ['Number 1', 'name', 'Number 2', 'name'];
    var i=0;
    while(i<arr.length)
   {

   str += i==0 ? "" : ","
    str+=arr[i];
    i++;
    str+=":";
    str+=arr[i];

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use string concatenation when there is another solution, simply because it's less readable and harder to maintain.

```js
var arr = ['Number 1', 'name', 'Number 2', 'name'];

var str = Array.from({length: arr.length / 2}).map(() => arr.splice(0, 2).join(' :')).join(', ');

document.body.innerHTML = `<pre>${str}</pre>`;
```